# Removing folder name when using nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

We have a CMS where some of the pages are accessed by going example.com/xyz

We need to make some of the site accessible using example1.com but keep the address bar the same, so for example going to example1.com goes to example.com/xyz, but still shows example1.com in the address bar.

I've done this by using proxy_pass which looks something like this.

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://example1.com/xyz;
}
```

This works in that I get example.com/xyz when I go to example1.com (and the addressbar stil shows example1.com)

I have also created a 2nd proxy_pass for the pages below /xyz

which looks something like this.

```
location /xyz {
proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

This works in that when I go to example1.com/xyz/hello I get the page available at example.com/xyz/hello (and the address bar still shows example1.com/xyz/hello)

Is there anyway of doing it so it it shows as being example1.com/hello i.e without the xyz.

I've tried the following

```
rewrite /xyz/[^/]*(.*) $1 break;
```

and

```
rewrite ^/xyz(/.*)$ $1 last;
```

but still the /xyz/ appears in the address.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Here's my full config

```
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 4G;
server_name example1.com;
passenger_enabled on;
root /home/<user>/current/public;
rails_env production;
keepalive_timeout 5;


location = / {
proxy_pass http://example1.com/<folder>; // This is to silently redirect the root of http://example1.com to http://example1.com/<folder>
}

location ~ ^/assets/ {
root /home/<user>/current/public;
expires max;
add_header Cache-Control public;
add_header ETag "";
break;
}


location /system {
proxy_pass http://www.example.com; // This is to silently redirect http://example1.com/system to example.com/system, but to still show example1.com/system in the address bar
}



location ^~/<folder> {
proxy_pass http://example.com/<folder>; // This silently redirects example1.com/ to example.com/<folder>
}
}
```

This all works in that

going to example1.com gives me the page at example.com/folder

Clicking the links on the page take me to the correct page on example.com, but show example1.com in the addressbar.

eg

example1.com/folder/history

I need to hide the folder part of it.

Comment: Your code and text contradict each other. Show real code.

Comment: The code is as it appears in the nginx virtualhost...i've just changed the sites real address to example.com, and the new address to example1.com...thanks

Comment: Well, in one sentence you go to example.com in other to example1.com. That's weird. Show block of code from `server {` to closing `}`, not this random lines